# Return a value if no record is found

Tags: sql, select, null, record

I have this simple statement that works:

```
SELECT idnumber FROM dbo.database WHERE number = '9823474'
```

If the number does not exist anywhere in the table, it fails. I would like to add something to this statement that says:
IF NO RECORD IS FOUND RETURN NULL INSTEAD OF NO ROW.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Give it that value in what row? There are no rows in which to give it a value.

Comment: "It fails". What is "it fails"? It simply returns no rows. That's "not failing", in my opinion...

Answer (score 93):

**Encapsulate the query in a sub-query** to transform "no row" to a `null` value.

I tested and verified this with [**PostgreSQL**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-overview.html), [**SQLite**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause), [**SQL Server**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx), and [**MySQL**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).

```
SELECT (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474) AS id;
```

In [**Oracle**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2130183) you have to select from the dummy 1-row table `DUAL`:

```
SELECT (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474) AS id FROM DUAL;
```

You *can* do the same in MySQL for compatibility reasons, but you don't have to.
Similar in [**Firebird**](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-database.html):

```
SELECT (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474) AS id FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

This does it for [**DB2**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysdummy1table.html) (like [Sean commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#comment66763417_8098816)):

```
SELECT (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474) AS id FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: Works well in Firebird. Thanks for doing the research.

Comment: I do not understand why sub-query encapsulation works.

Comment: @8.8.8.8: Because "no row" from a subquery is converted to a `NULL` value in the `SELECT` list. It's a logic necessity.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a function to do this. But this definitely works

Comment: @chrismarx: If your query returns no row (nothing at all), there is no place for a function to catch that. So we need an outer `SELECT` - and then we don't even need a function.

Comment: This works in DB2 as well, provided you substitute `DUAL` with `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`.

Comment: What if I want to return 0 instead of null when no row is found?

Comment: @MohitAtray: Use `COALESCE`. As in: `SELECT COALESCE((SELECT ...), 0) AS id;` And it's easy with the `UNION` variant.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!! :) Using Oracle I was looking to fetch the max number and always getting null instead of 0.00.


**SELECT
     NVL((
         select max(Valor) AS VALOR
         from SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
          where 1=1
         AND acc_no=acc_no
     ), 0.00) INTO acc_bal FROM DUAL**

Answer (score 9):

To make it more simplier, this should work fine. If you assign this to a variable based on the datatype of your idnumber than you would be able to evaluate whether the value is null or the actual idnumber return.

```
SELECT ISNULL(
      (
         SELECT idnumber 
         FROM dbo.database 
         WHERE number = '9823474'
      ), NULL)
```

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have the ISNULL function.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select isnull(sum(Amount),0) as Amt from BeginningBalance where CustomerID = @CustomerID
Union all
Select isnull(sum(Amount),0) as Amt from SalesOrders where CustomerID = @CustomerID
Union all
Select isnull(sum(Amount),0) as Amt from SalesInvoices where CustomerID = @CustomerID
//Data Row Result if no data is present at Beginning Balance Table
// example 

Amt
2000  // amount from sales orders
1000  // amount from sales invoices
```

---

```
// if the 1st select statement return no data use this
SELECT (select sum(Amount) from BeginningBalance 
        where CustomerID = @CustomerID) as Amt
Union all
Select sum(Amount) as Amt from SalesOrders where CustomerID = @CustomerID
Union all
Select sum(Amount) as Amt from SalesInvoices where CustomerID = @CustomerID
```

Result :

```
Amt
NULL  // amount from BeginningBalance
2000  // amount from sales orders
1000  // amount from sales invoices
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this for MySql

```
SELECT IFNULL(ColumnA,"1") AS ColumnA , COUNT(1) AS Total FROM table 
WHERE ID = 1 LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way for me was to use the good old `IF THEN ELSE` trick! Works with all SQL flavors.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbItem WHERE price >= 10)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbItem WHERE price >= 10
END
ELSE
  SELECT 'No record'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standalone proof-of-concept in Oracle, which returns a real value instead of NULL

In Oracle, the "dual" table always has a column called "dummy" which contains 'X'. Therefore, the following statement will never return a row.

```
select * from dual where dummy='123';
```

So this statement will always return "NO RECORD FOUND" thanks to the nvl function

```
select nvl((select * from dual where dummy='123'),'NO RECORD FOUND')
value 
from dual;
```

but, if you really want NULL you can do this (as described above)

```
select (select * from dual where dummy='123') value from dual;
```

Of course, swap the above select statement with your own

Answer (score 0):

You can use [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)

```
COALESCE((SELECT idnumber FROM dbo.database WHERE number = '9823474'),0)
```

Replace `0` with any value that you would like to return if the select query returns no rows.

Comment: `COALESCE` catches `null` values, but can't catch "no row".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter when dealing with single column, moving COALESCE outside the SELECT does the trick