# Return a value if select returned null

Tags: firebird

I need to return a value if select returned null. however I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found) by putting a query in a sub-query

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474), 4) AS id FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

The query above would return `Null` because the value 9823474 does not exist in the table but I want to return a value in that case (for ex 4) so I found the only solution to use select inside sub query and then `COALESCE` would work, If I did not do that `COALESCE` will also return `Null`.

Is it the only solution ?

Comment: Give us more informaton about how you suppose to use the value? What programming language do you use?

Comment: It's not clear what your query is supposed to be doing. Can you [edit] to be more specific? The inner `SELECT` tries to get an ID from Tbl and returns 4 if one is not found, but where does RDB$DATABASE fit into the equation? It's not needed at all, unless there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ more description posted. I am looking for SQL solution

Comment: In Delphi we would write someting like this: q.SQL.Text = 'SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474'; q.ExecQuery; if q.EOF then Result := 4 else Result := q.Fields[0].AsInteger.

Comment: @KenWhite RDB$DATABASE always has a single row,  so it is just an SQL-compliant way of Ms SQL select-without-from.  In Oracle the same usually is arranged as SELECT (expression) FROM SYSTEM.DUAL

Comment: @Arioch'The: Ah, got it. It's the FB version of Oracle's `dual`. Thanks.

Comment: You should really say what you gonna do with that value later. Maybe we can suggest the idea that does not directly substitute for that your query, but provides for a larger problem solution without such a request at all

Comment: @KenWhite I actually always found it counter-intuitive that DUAL has a single row,  not duo :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The: I found a lot of things about Oracle counter-intuitive. :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The I dont want that. It is complex and I already have a solution, This way I learn something new like the answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not an only way for example

```
Select first 1 id from (
    Select id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474

    Union All

    Select 4 from rdb$database)
```

Or you can use anonymous procedure http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=execute_block

```
 EXECUTE BLOCK RETURNS ( id integer )
 AS
 BEGIN
      IF ( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474) )
      THEN id = 9823474;
      ELSE id = 4;

      SUSPEND;
 END
```

... there always are many methods there

Comment: My edit refused !! `Returning` should be `RETURNS`, add parenthesis around `Exists` and add `suspend;` at the end

Comment: @Wel yeah, mixed with insert-returning. About suspend - it only is needed for SELECT-from-SP. But i ain't sure you can select from execute-block. For execute-procedure (singular result) for what i remember suspend does not give anything. And anyway, we did not saw the grand picture why you want it and how you gonna use it.

Comment: I needed just a solution thanks. `Suspend;` is needed with `Returns` http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq202/

Comment: @Wel your link starts with "If you write a SELECT that should return some rows". I do not write such a for-select loop.

Comment: If you tried without `suspend;` you will get `null`. The link display just an example, it does has to be for..select

Comment: @Val - that's because there are different types of request. The request of "fetch from select" type would need suspend, but the request of "call stored procedure" kind should not

Guess that is some kind of non coherency between docs, engines, IBExpert and dbexpress. Would have to ask on forums

Comment: @Val glanced into README.execute_block.txt. Yes, you're right. If output parameters present, server always assume select-type request. It is not like procedures work, but that si how it is.

Comment: This might only be academic, but there is no explicit guarantee, that the result from the second UNION ALL query is not the first one in the result set: "When a SELECT statement is executed, the result set is not sorted in any way." Nevertheless: Helpful answer.