# SQL: How to return all NULLs when no record found?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a simple SELECT...

```
SELECT  TETmeetingID,
        DateID,
        WeekNo,
        TETID,
        TradeStaffID,
        EngStaffID,
        MathsStaffID,
        IoTStaffID,
        Others,
        TradeStaffPresent,
        EngStaffPresent,
        MathsStaffPresent,
        IoTStaffPresent,
        CurricTrade,
        CurricEnglish,
        CurricMaths,
        CurricIoT,
        CurricAlign,
        Notes,
        WeeksToGo,
        TotalWeeks,
        CreatedDate,
        CreatedBy,
        Complete,
        CompletedDate,
        CompletedBy
FROM tblTETMeeting
WHERE TETmeetingID = @SomeParameter
```

Works of course when the `WHERE` clause returns `true`.

But if it does not, I want to at least see ONE record with NULLs in every column.

How can I do this please? And I chose the above example to show the possible number of columns I could be using, so if there's a more generic query that can "determine" the columns and not have to hard-code them into the answer, that would be preferred.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've tried `WITH TIES`, but that also did not return a single record. Maybe I was doing it wrong. I've also tried the `UNION NULL, NULL,` etc trick, but that is messy when the number of columns could be undefined 'n'. The only way I can do this properly, but I am still forced to provide the correct number of NULLs is with a `CTE` type query.

```
WITH CTE (    SELECT  TETmeetingID,
            DateID,
            WeekNo,
            TETID,
            TradeStaffID,
            EngStaffID,
            MathsStaffID,
            IoTStaffID,
            Others,
            TradeStaffPresent,
            EngStaffPresent,
            MathsStaffPresent,
            IoTStaffPresent,
            CurricTrade,
            CurricEnglish,
            CurricMaths,
            CurricIoT,
            CurricAlign,
            Notes,
            WeeksToGo,
            TotalWeeks,
            CreatedDate,
            CreatedBy,
            Complete,
            CompletedDate,
            CompletedBy
    FROM tblTETMeeting
    WHERE TETmeetingID = @SomeParameter) AS tbl1

select * from CTE WHERE cte.TETmeetingID IS NOT NULL UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL, etc
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found

Comment: This sort of thing is best handled at the application layer, not in the query.

Comment: Other than the fact that I don't think this should be done in SQL, the easiest way to do it (IMO) is with an IF/ELSE statement. e.g. `if exists (select 1 from tblTETMeeting WHERE TETmeetingID = @SomeParameter) THEN myQuery ELSE SELECT NULL, NULL...`. Alternatively, the answers in whizzle's link work if there's only one row expected.

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer in @whizzle's link is really only useful if you are returning a single ***field***, which is not the case here.

Comment: @sstan the last part of whizzle's link can be adapted to work for any number of columns. e.g. `select top 1 * from (myquery union all select null,null,null...) t order by case when TETmeetingID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` but yes it doesn't directly answer the question here.

Comment: @sstan Thanks Stan, that's the problem. Yes one column is easy, but where I have multiple columns? And what if I am forced to use SELECT * because the underlying data source comes from a legacy system? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM
(SELECT 1 As DummyColumn) As DummyTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
tblTETMeeting C
ON TETmeetingID = @SomeParameter
```

Comment: Perfect! Yes that worked. But how?! How does a single SELECT 1 do this?

Comment: The table called `DummyTable` is just one record with one column. So now you have one record _no matter what_. Then you optionally join it to your 'real' record which may or may not exist. By optionally I mean use an `OUTER JOIN`. The 1 doesn't mean anything. You could use `(SELECT 'Mastodon' As MyFavouriteBand) As MyFavouriteStuff` and it would still work. But a warning: `SELECT *` is bad practice for many reasons - don't get into the habit of using it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do.

The idea is to add a flag column and an extra row with NULL in all columns except the flag column.  In this example, `ConditionTrue` is the flag column. 1 as true and 0 as false.  This means that if the predicate in `WHERE` is true, the result will be all the rows returned with `ConditionTrue` of 1 *plus* a row of null with `ConditioinTrue` of 0.  On the other hand, if nothing was returned, it'll be just the the row of null with `ConditionTrue` of 0.  By putting the result into a temp table, you can then filter out unwanted rows and columns.

If the predicate is true, then there will always be 2 or more rows.  So you can check @@ROWCOUNT to your advantage.  1 means no hit, bigger means hit.

Lastly, I don't want to type all 26 columns again, so I dropped the `ConditionTrue` column and used `SELECT *` as a shortcut.  If you don't mind the flag column, leave it be, or you can move the `ALTER` statement before the `IF` block and filter out differently, like `TETmeetingID IS NOT NULL`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#tblTETMeeting','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Tempdb..#tblTETMeeting;

DECLARE @COUNTS INT;

SELECT  TETmeetingID,
        DateID,
        WeekNo,
        TETID,
        TradeStaffID,
        EngStaffID,
        MathsStaffID,
        IoTStaffID,
        Others,
        TradeStaffPresent,
        EngStaffPresent,
        MathsStaffPresent,
        IoTStaffPresent,
        CurricTrade,
        CurricEnglish,
        CurricMaths,
        CurricIoT,
        CurricAlign,
        Notes,
        WeeksToGo,
        TotalWeeks,
        CreatedDate,
        CreatedBy,
        Complete,
        CompletedDate,
        CompletedBy,
        1 AS ConditionTrue
INTO #tblTETMeeting
FROM tblTETMeeting
WHERE TETmeetingID = @SomeParameter
UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL, 0;

SET @COUNTS = @@ROWCOUNT; 

IF @COUNTS > 1 

    SELECT * FROM #tblTETMeeting WHERE ConditionTrue = 1;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE #tblTETMeeting 
            DROP COLUMN ConditionTrue;
        SELECT * FROM #tblTETMeeting;
    END;
```

Comment: Thank you for that long answer, but I'd prefer the other answer where it's all in one single SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `UNION` is the counterpart of logical `OR`:

```
SELECT TETmeetingID
  FROM tblTETMeeting
 WHERE TETmeetingID = @SomeParameter
UNION
SELECT NULL AS TETmeetingID  -- don't make me write them all out!
  FROM tblTETMeeting
 WHERE TETmeetingID <> @SomeParameter
```

Speaking of logic, remember in SQL a search condition (`WHERE` clause) can evaluate `true`, `false` and `unknown` due to SQL's confusing (and inconsistently applied) three-value logic. So if `TETmeetingID` or `@SomeParameter` can ever be null then you may need to add some code to handle this.