# Select the nth highest value in a column and null if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve the LeetCode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/description/; my solution so far (see also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4752cb/1) is:

```
SELECT Salary AS SecondHighestSalary 
FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1;
```

The problem is that my solution is failing on the following test case:

[image]

In other words, it is simply returning no results rather than returning `NULL`. How can I make it return `NULL` if there is no second-highest salary?

**Update**

Following [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found), I tried to encapsulate the query in a sub-query:

```
SELECT (SELECT Salary 
FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1) AS SecondHighestSalary;
```

However, this fails on a different test case in which there are two employees with the same salary:

[image]

In this case, we are apparently also supposed to return `NULL`. How can I adapt the 'closer to a solution' query above to handle this?

Comment: what if two (or more) Employee have the same highest salary... do we return the highest salary? or do we return the next lower salary?

Comment: Spencer, in this case we return the next lower salary (although this is not clear from LeetCode's problem statement; I discovered this from a failing test case).

Comment: the problem here is.. How about the related person of that particular salary if we can say 20 of persons has the second highest salary.. can we determine who's person is it for that particular salary if we only need one salary with a distinct query. I think the `LeetCode's problem`  is not too clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here OFFSET 1 means without 1st one (EX:if you don't want to display first 2 then OFFSET will be 2)

```
SELECT
    Salary AS SecondHighestSalary 
FROM
    Employee

ORDER BY
    Salary

LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a query which finally passes the tests:

```
SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT Salary 
FROM Employee 
ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1) AS SecondHighestSalary;
```

It seems more intuitive than the other solutions, no?

Answer (score 2):

Select another row that returns null, using `union all` so order is preserved, then return only the first row of that:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Salary AS SecondHighestSalary 
    FROM Employee 
    ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL
)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With the current query, we could just wrap it in another query, and use an aggregate function

```
   SELECT MAX(v.salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
     FROM (
            SELECT e.Salary
              FROM Employee e
             ORDER BY e.Salary DESC
             LIMIT 1, 1
          ) v
```

---

What should second highest salary be given this set ...

```
 id  salary
 --  ------
  1    1000
  2    1000
  4     750
```

Should we return 1000, or return 750? If we want to return 750, we could do something like this:

```
   SELECT MAX(s.salary) AS SecondHighestSalary
     FROM ( SELECT MAX(e.salary) AS max_salary
              FROM Employee e
          ) h
     JOIN Employee s
       ON s.salary < h.max_salary
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFNULL` :

```sql
SELECT
  IFNULL( (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    `salary` 
  FROM
    `Employee` 
  ORDER BY
    `salary` DESC LIMIT 1, 1), NULL )
)
AS `SecondHighestSalary`
```

Returns `NULL` if first query returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Safe with Distinct excluding null values:

```
SELECT distinct Salary AS SecondHighestSalary 
FROM Employee where salary is not null ORDER BY salary desc limit 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first get the top two values
then handle the case of null and the normal case separately

```sql
select case
when min(top2.salary)=max(top2.salary) then null
else min(top2.salary) end
as SecondHighestSalary
from 
(select e.salary from employee e order by e.salary desc limit 2) as top2;
```