# Do all groups have equal total power for given subgroup?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate

I have a PostgreSQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (man_id, subgroup, power, grp)
AS VALUES
    ( 1, 'Sub_A',  1, 'Group_A' ),
    ( 2, 'Sub_B', -1, 'Group_A' ),
    ( 3, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B' ),
    ( 4, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_B' ),
    ( 5, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_A' ),
    ( 6, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_A' ),
    ( 7, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B' ),
    ( 8, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_B' );
```

The power calculation works like this:

*Total Power of Subgroup Sub_A in the grp Group_A is (1 + (-1) ) = 0

Total Power of Subgroup Sub_B in the grp Group_A is ((-1) + 1 ) = 0

Total Power of Subgroup Sub_A in the grp Group_B is ((-1) + (-1) ) = -2

Total Power of Subgroup Sub_B in the grp Group_B is (1 + 1 ) = 2*

*So the power of Sub_A in the Group_A is not equal to power of Sub_A in the Group_B

So the power of Sub_B in the Group_A is not equal to power of Sub_B in the Group_B*

I want to query the database with a `subgroup` name. If for a same `subgroup` name power is equal across all the other `grp` names, then it will return `True`, else `False`.

As an example, `sub_A` and `sub_B` both will return `False`. What would be the recommended way to do this?

I want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo (solution query will be added)
WHERE subgroup = 'sub_A'
```

And it returns `False`.

Comment: Please don't cross post.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix some distracting typos, orthogonal to the question (or so I assume). Please always disclose your version of Postgres. Roughly how many rows, distinct groups and subgroups? Cardinality and value frequencies may be relevant for choosing the best query.

Comment: what result do you expect if the subgroup `Sub_A` does not exist at all, or exists for only 1 group. I feel the choice isn't clear, as one might alternatively want `NULL`, `FALSE` or `TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Read the question carefully

> I want to query the database with a subgroup name.

And:

> I want something like
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM foo (solution query will be added)
> WHERE subgroup = 'Sub_A'
> ```

The important point for performance is to exclude irrelevant rows early and **only compute aggregates for the given subgroup**. Then (assuming more than a few distinct subgroups), an index on `(subgroup)` can help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo (subgroup);
```

Each of the following queries returns `FALSE` if at least two groups have different total sums for the given subgroup, and `TRUE` in *all* other cases (with a minor exception for query 5, see below).

#### Query 1

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT total_power) = 1
FROM  (
   SELECT sum(power) AS total_power
   FROM   foo
   WHERE  subgroup = 'Sub_B'  -- exclude irrelevant rows early!
   GROUP  BY grp
   ) sub;
```

#### Query 2

```
SELECT count(*) = 1
FROM  (
   SELECT true
   FROM  (
      SELECT sum(power) AS total_power
      FROM   foo
      WHERE  subgroup = 'Sub_C'
      GROUP  BY grp
      ) sub2
   GROUP  BY total_power
   ) sub2;
```

#### Query 3

```
SELECT count(*) OVER () = 1
FROM  (
   SELECT sum(power) AS total_power
   FROM   foo
   WHERE  subgroup = 'Sub_A'
   GROUP  BY grp
   ) sub
GROUP  BY total_power
LIMIT  1;
```

#### Query 4

```
(
SELECT FALSE
FROM  (
   SELECT sum(power) AS total_power
   FROM   foo
   WHERE  subgroup = 'Sub_A'
   GROUP  BY grp
   ) sub
GROUP  BY total_power
OFFSET 1
LIMIT  1
)
UNION ALL
SELECT TRUE
LIMIT 1;
```

This one is special. Related answers with explanation:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)
- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339715/way-to-try-multiple-selects-till-a-result-is-available/14365613#14365613)

#### Query 5

```
SELECT min(total_power) = max(total_power)  -- can fail for NULL values
FROM  (
   SELECT sum(power) AS total_power
   FROM   foo
   WHERE  subgroup = 'Sub_A'
   GROUP  BY grp
   ) sub;
```

The last can fail if `NULL` values in power are allowed. (But you would have to define expected results in this case anyway.)

I ran an **extensive test** and found all queries to perform about the same under ideal conditions:

***db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d0f55c9c98385d76d732b658f8323cea)***

Query 5 tended to be a tad bit faster than the rest.

Comment: as always, your answers are illustrative. I was wondering if you could compare my solution to the 5 alternatives you have tested. I'm curious what effect avoiding a subquery in favour of a window-expression & sorting has on performance in this setting.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: I added [your smart query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50920135/939860) to the test battery: works, and about the same performance as the rest: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=39628360b8711060bb79f0588229f8b3)*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in your CREATE TABLE statement, 'sub_A' is meant to be 'Sub_A' (because Postgres is case-sensitive), and that your `power` values are actually integers (if they aren't, just add casts; the code below is simpler without them), then you can calculate the power for each subgroup within a group as follows:

```
select
    subgroup,
    grp,
    sum(power) as sum_power
from
    foo
group by
    subgroup,
    grp
```

To determine whether all of the total power values for a subgroup are the same, just check that the minimum and maximum values are the same.  Convert the previous query into a subquery, where the main query does that comparison, as follows:

```
select
    subgroup
from (
    select
        subgroup,
        grp,
        sum(power) as sum_power
    from
        foo
    group by
        subgroup,
        grp
    ) as subpwr
group by
    subgroup
having
    min(sum_power) = max(sum_power);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's 1 way not *yet* mentioned by the other answers

```
SELECT SUM(power) = FIRST_VALUE(SUM(power)) OVER () powpow 
FROM foo
WHERE subgroup = 'Sub_A'
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY powpow
LIMIT 1

-- returns:
-- false if some values differ
-- true if all values are the same
-- no rows if the where condition fails to match any rows.
```