# SQL subquery to fetch rows by column values

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a PostgreSQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(man_id, subgroup, power, grp)
AS VALUES
    (1, 'Sub_A',  4, 'Group_A'),
    (2, 'Sub_B', -1, 'Group_A'),
    (3, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B'),
    (4, 'Sub_B',  6, 'Group_B'),
    (5, 'Sub_A',  5, 'Group_A'),
    (6, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_A'),
    (7, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B'),
    (8, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_B'),
    (9, 'Sub_C',  2, 'Group_B');
```

The power calculation works like this:

- Total Power of Subgroup Sub_A in the grp Group_A is (4 + 5 ) = 9
- Total Power of Subgroup Sub_B in the grp Group_A is ((-1) + 1 ) = 0
- Total Power of Subgroup Sub_A in the grp Group_B is ((-1) + (-1) ) = -2
- Total Power of Subgroup Sub_B in the grp Group_B is (6 + 2 ) = 8

So the power of Sub_A in the Group_A is not equal to power of Sub_A in the Group_B

So the power of Sub_B in the Group_A is not equal to power of Sub_B in the Group_B

I want to query the database and fetch the rows where, for a same `subgroup` name total `power` is not equal across all the other `grp` names.

What would be the recommended way to do this?

I can find the sum of total power:

```
SELECT sum(power) AS total_power
FROM   foo
GROUP  BY grp
```

MySQL solution will be accepted as well.

Comment: Never used PostgreSQL but it would seem this can all be done with a left join on 2 sub querys with the Foo table.

Comment: MySQL solution is fine too

Comment: Your description isn't clear to me. What do you mean by "is not equal across all the other `grp` names"? And what would be the records fetched with your example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM  (
   SELECT subgroup
   FROM  (
      SELECT subgroup, grp, sum(power) AS total_power
      FROM   foo
      GROUP  BY subgroup, grp
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING min(total_power) <> max(total_power)  -- can fail for NULL values;
   ) sg
JOIN foo f USING (subgroup);
```

In your example all rows qualify except for the last one with 'Sub_C'.

Closely related to your previous question:

- [Do all groups have equal total power for given subgroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50918436/do-all-groups-have-equal-total-power-for-given-subgroup/50920065#50920065)

Similar explanation and considerations.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cbb27a027a05f636749e7b0db2c01231)*

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to phrase your problem is that you want to total the power for subgroup in a group, then find if a subgroup with the same name exists in another group with a different power.

The first step is to total the powers like you want:

```
SELECT grp, subgroup, sum(power) as power
FROM foo
GROUP BY grp, subgroup
```

That should give you a result like:

```
grp      subgroup  power
-------  --------  -----
Group_A  Sub_A      9
Group_A  Sub_B      0
Group_B  Sub_A     -2
Group_B  Sub_B      8
Group_B  Sub_C      2
```

Once you have that, you can use a CTE to join the results with itself for the comparison to get what you want.  You don't specify whether you want `Sub_C` to appear, if 'not existing' qualifies as having a 'different total power', then you would want to use a left join and check for nulls in alias `b`.  The `<` in the join makes it so that each difference only appears once with the lower order group as grp1.

```
WITH totals AS (
    SELECT grp, subgroup, sum(power) as power
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY grp, subgroup
    ORDER BY grp, subgroup
)
SELECT a.subgroup,
       a.grp as grp1, a.power as Power1,
       b.grp as grp2, b.power as Power2
FROM totals a
    INNER JOIN totals b ON b.subgroup = a.subgroup
                           and a.grp < b.grp
WHERE b.power <> a.power
ORDER BY a.subgroup, a.grp, b.grp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with totals as (
    select grp, subgroup, sum(power) as total_power
    from foo
    group by grp, subgroup
)
select * from totals t1
where t1.total_power <> all (
    select t2.total_power from totals t2
    where t2.subgroup = t.subgroup and t2.grp <> t1.grp
)
```

or

```
with totals as (
    select grp, subgroup, sum(power) as total_power
    from foo
    group by grp, subgroup
), matches as (
    select grp, subgroup, count(*) over (partition by subgroup, total_power) as matches
)
select * from counts where matches = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             min(sum_value)) over (partition by group) as min_sum_value,
             max(sum_value)) over (partition by group) as max_sum_value,
      from (select f.*,
                   sum(value) over (partition by subgroup, group) as sum_value
            from foo f
           ) f
      ) f
where min_sum_value <> max_sum_value;
```