# Setting a value to the result of a subquery in a function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a function for a trigger that checks if the date in a new entry in a relation is bigger than the entry in an other relation. If that is the case, I want to update the date value in my new relation to the date value in my other relation:

```
create or replace function curDate()
returns trigger as $$
Begin
    if (new.date >= (select date from other where new.name = other.name )) then
        set new.date = (select date from playlist where new.name = other.name );
    end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

I get a syntax error on:`set new.date = (select date from playlist where new.name = other.name )`

However, this works fine:

```
create or replace function curDate()
    returns trigger as $$
    declare dateVar date;
Begin
    dateVar := (select date from other where new.name = other.name);
    if (new.datum >= dateVar) then
        new.datum = dateVar;
    end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Why is that?

Comment: The keyword `set` is just redundant in an assignment in plpgsql. Btw, the function should `return new;`.

Comment: We need to see the *trigger* to get the trigger function right completely. And always your version of Postgres. `date` or `datum`? Are all involved columns defined `NOT NULL` and `other.name` `UNIQUE`?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all involved columns `NOT NULL` and `other.name UNIQUE` to avoid complications.

Use *one* `SELECT` query assigning `NEW.datum`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_cur_date()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT o.datum
   FROM   other o
   WHERE  o.name  = NEW.name
   AND    o.datum < NEW.datum

   UNION ALL SELECT NEW.datum
   LIMIT  1

   INTO   NEW.datum;

   RETURN NEW;  -- required for BEFORE INSERT trigger
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For a trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER playlist_ins_bef
BEFORE INSERT ON playlist
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_cur_date();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6f83251ff1d70ff818c4f0b3507641cf)*

[`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) <sub>(*not to confused with SQL [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html), the use of which is discouraged*)</sub> can do the assignment just like [`=` or `:=`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT). No <strike>`SET`</strike> here.

If no row qualifies, a plain `SELECT INTO` would assign `NULL`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

> ... target will be set to the first row returned by the query, or to nulls if the query returned no rows.

Appending `UNION ALL SELECT NEW.datum LIMIT 1` defaults to the original value instead. See:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)

This way, we only ever execute *one* query with *one* assignment.

Answer (score 0):

To store the result of a query into a variable, use [select into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

```
create or replace function curDate()
returns trigger as $$
Begin
  if (new.date >= (select date from other where new.name = other.name )) then
    select date 
      into new.date 
    from other 
    where new.name = other.name;
  end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

This can be further optimized by only running the SELECT once.

```
create or replace function curDate()
returns trigger as $$
declare
   l_date date;
Begin
  select date 
    into l_date
  from other 
  where new.name = other.name;

  if (new.date >= l_date) then
    new.date := l_date;
  end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```