# Change number of Rows Affected by Update

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, plpgsql

I am trying to achieve here is to basically override **0 rows Updated**, when UPDATE is issued in-case the actual PK/UK value doesn't exist in the table. This is what I have done:

Actual Table:

```
CREATE TABLE fdrgiit.vereine( 
team numeric(10) primary key, 
punkte int not null, 
serie int not null 
);
```

Dummy Table:

```
CREATE TABLE fdrgiit.dummyup 
( 
id numeric(1) PRIMARY KEY, 
datetest timestamp 
);
```

Inserted records in both the tables:

```
insert into vereine(team,punkte,serie) values(1, 50, 1); 
insert into vereine(team,punkte,serie) values(2, 30, 1); 
insert into vereine(team,punkte,serie) values(3, 25, 1); 
insert into vereine(team,punkte,serie) values(4, 37, 2); 
insert into dummyup values(1, now());
```

Created the following function and trigger:

```
create or replace function updateover() 
returns trigger as 
$BODY$ 
begin 
if EXISTS (select 1 FROM vereine WHERE team = new.team ) then 
RETURN NEW; 
else 
UPDATE fdrgiit.dummyup set datetest=now() where id=1; 
RETURN NULL; 
end if; 
end; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

create trigger update_redundancy 
before update on vereine 
for each row 
execute procedure updateover() ;
```

But when I execute an UPDATE like this on the , I am still get **0 rows affected**

```
update vereine set punkte=87 where team=5;
```

Kindly review and please suggest if this is something that can be done.

Comment: The trigger will never be fired if the row to be updated does not exist (which is the case for `where team = 5` in your example). So the EXISTS check is completely useless, your trigger function isn't even called.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So are you saying there is no way to override **0 Rows Affected** message?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trigger anything with an UPDATE that does not affect row as triggers are only fired for affected rows.

But you could wrap your alternative `UPDATE` into a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateover()
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
   UPDATE dummyup
   SET    datetest = now()
   WHERE  id = 1
   RETURNING 2;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

... and run your `UPDATE` nested like this:

```
WITH upd AS (
   UPDATE vereine
   SET    punkte = 87
   WHERE  team = 5  -- does not exist!
   RETURNING 1
   )
SELECT 1 FROM upd
UNION ALL
SELECT updateover()
LIMIT 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=04ed43d334efb2adb85550b28f40bdf6)*

If no row qualifies for an `UPDATE`, then 1st outer `SELECT 1 FROM upd` returns no row and Postgres keeps processing the 2nd `SELECT updateover()`. But if at least one row is affected, the final `SELECT` is never executed. Exactly what you want.

This updates `dummyup` *one* time if the `UPDATE` on `vereine` does not affect any rows; never several times. But that's ok, since `now()` is `STABLE` for the duration of the transaction.

Related:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)