# Is SELECT "faster" than function with nested INSERT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, upsert

I'm using a function that inserts a row to a table if it doesn't exist, then returns the id of the row.

Whenever I put the function inside a `SELECT` statement, with values that don't exist in the table yet, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = function(123);
```

... it returns an empty row. However, running it again with the same values will return the row with the values I want to see.

Why does this happen? Is the `INSERT` running behind the `SELECT` speed? Or does PostgreSQL cache the table when it didn't exist, and at next run, it displays the result?

Here's a ready to use example of how this issue can occur:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table(
id INTEGER,
tvalue boolean
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(user_id INTEGER)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
DECLARE
    __user_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id = $1')
    USING user_id
    INTO __user_id;

    IF __user_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN __user_id;

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO test_table(id, tvalue)
        VALUES (user_id, TRUE) 
        RETURNING id
        INTO __user_id;
        RETURN __user_id;
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id = test_function(4);
```

To reproduce the issue, pass any integer that doesn't exist in the table, yet.

Comment: It’s not “speed”, it sounds like transactional visibility. Consider posting a *full* example, which should also show the INSERT/UPDATE relationship.

Comment: im trying to make a smaller example, the full one is quite boring to read trough

Comment: @user2864740 completed a quite simple example, i hope it will give you some context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is broken in multiple places.

- No need for dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`.
- `SELECT *` in the function is wrong.
- Your table definition should have a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `(id)`.
- Most importantly, the final `SELECT` statement is bound to fail. Since the [function is `VOLATILE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) (has to be), it is evaluated once for *every* existing row in the table. Even if that worked, it would be a performance nightmare. But it does not. Like @user2864740 commented, there is *also* a problem with visibility. Postgres checks every *existing* row against the result of the function, which in turn adds 1 or more rows, and those rows are not yet in the snapshot the `SELECT` is operating on.

  <strike>`SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id = test_function(4);`</strike>

This would work (but see below!):

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id     int PRIMARY KEY  --!
, tvalue bool
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(_user_id int)
  RETURNS test_table LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   WITH ins AS (
      INSERT INTO test_table(id, tvalue)
      VALUES (_user_id, TRUE) 
      ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
      RETURNING *
      )
   TABLE ins
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id = _user_id
   LIMIT 1
$func$;
```

And replace your `SELECT` with just:

```
SELECT * FROM test_function(1);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ac893b858d43a1da21444363c1badf98)*

Related:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

There is still a **race condition** for concurrent calls. If that can happen, consider:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)