# COALESCE doesn't seem to fire in Postgres 12 SQL stored function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, coalesce

Using Postgres 12.x, I've just run into a weird problem. For some reason, I'm not getting `COALESCE` to work in a stored SQL function. Meaning, I get `NULL` instead of my first non-null value.

I suspect that I've missed something obvioius, but can't see it. Can anyone spot what the problem is? I've built a stand-alone example that reproduces the issue.

Thanks

## Test Setup

```
BEGIN;

------------------------------------
-- Define table
------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lookup_table CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lookup_table (
    id    uuid    NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL, -- Values are geneated by an outside system.
    name_ citext  NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

------------------------------------
-- Seed
------------------------------------
INSERT INTO lookup_table (id, name_) 
     VALUES  ('6ea225f3-9819-49eb-bdb8-f3ae23af6337', 'John'),
             ('ae2282c6-ca9b-413f-b182-a1ca69fc3c78', 'Alice'),
             ('7ee1ce1b-4efc-426c-a6f8-5b2375cb357e', 'Magrite'),
             ('71c3d96a-3ac7-454e-bfff-e5551428c017', 'Arjun');

------------------------------------
-- Define the lookup fnction
------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lookup_function (id_in uuid)
     RETURNS citext AS

$BODY$

-- For some reason, COALESCE doesn't work here, but does outside of a function. Weird.
-- Tried with CTE, same same.
SELECT COALESCE (name_ , '') FROM lookup_table WHERE id = id_in;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL;

------------------------------------
-- Test it out
------------------------------------
SELECT 'Alice' AS description,
       lookup_function ('ae2282c6-ca9b-413f-b182-a1ca69fc3c78') AS result
       UNION ALL
       
SELECT 'Should return an empty string, returns NULL instead'           AS description,
       lookup_function ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS result
```

## Standard Call

For comparison, here's a standard call right in a `SELECT` that works fine:

```
select coalesce (name_, '') 
  from lookup_table
 where id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
 -- Returns an empty string, not NULL.
```

But, in a SQL function, this expression returns `NULL` instead.

## CTE Attempt

Here's my stab at using a CTE to help out in the function, but I still get back `NULL`.

```
------------------------------------
-- Define the lookup fnction
------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lookup_function (id_in uuid)
     RETURNS citext AS

$BODY$

WITH lookup_result AS (
   select name_ from lookup_table where id = id_in 
 )
 
SELECT CASE WHEN name_ IS NULL THEN ''
            ELSE name_ END
       FROM lookup_result

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: I don't see that working period: `select coalesce(name_, 'test') from lookup_table where id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
 coalesce 
----------
(0 rows)
` You will need to show the `CTE` that does work. I'm guessing there is a `JOIN` that is providing a value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated the example to show that the expression works as expected in a straight `SELECT`. The CTE (or a subquery) didn't make any difference on the function's behavior, so I left the example in its simplest form. And, in this case, no JOINs, it's really a straight lookup.

Comment: No it doesn't. Add `pg_typeof(coalesce (name_, ''))` and you will nothing is returned.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8098816/939860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lookup function doesn't return anything from the select statement inside it as the where clause fails.  The coalesce is never executed therefore.
A null is returned by default.

You can rewrite the select as:
`select coalesce((SELECT name_ FROM lookup_table WHERE id = id_in),'');`

Answer (score 0):

The coalesce will turn NULL value for name_  into the empty string.  But you don't have a NULL value for that column, you have zero rows.  This gets converted to NULL at a later stage, where the coalesce can't get its hands on it.

Maybe you want this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lookup_function (id_in uuid)
     RETURNS citext AS                                                   
$BODY$                                                         
SELECT COALESCE (name_ , '') FROM (values (id_in))f(x) left join lookup_table on id = x;    
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly too! I'm going to go with the previous answer, just as I find the code simpler to follow.