# Left join - coalesce does not work if no rows returned

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I want to do a simple left join using ids from table 1 and table 2. `coalesce()` only works if a value is `null` but when it is "no rows returned" it will not work.

```
left join table2 t2
        on t1.id = t2.id
        and coalesce(t1.id2, 1) = coalesce(t2.id2, 1)
```

The `id2` in table 1 is always null when it is blank, but for table 2 the record may not entirely exist, hence there is no null value. How do I print the value of "1" if no rows were returned for `coalesce(t2.id2, 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

This answer most likely fits your use case by encapsulating your query with another select query it will detect your no value to null by assigning it to a new column.

[image]

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8098816/19378826) from another post